# Sometimes returns old (possibly cached?) values from Workbooks in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

There are just under 2,000 excel reports in an SharePoint (Office 365) website and I am required to run a main report twice daily to get values from all of those 2,000 reports.  I use something similar to the following to get the information from these reports:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "='https://oursite.sharepoint.com/" & path2 & "/[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!$D$9"
```

We define path2 / filename above which are all fine.

This normally works fine and brings back the correct results however sometimes it'll bring old values through even though nobody has changed the reports on SharePoint.

I don't have any prior experience to working with SharePoint other than this so was wondering if there is some automatic caching or something similar?

If so is there a way to turn it off as we only want the latest results, perhaps something in the connection string used in Excel?

Connection String looks like:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Office.List.OLEDB.2.0;Data Source="";ApplicationName=Excel;Version=12.0.0.0
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is versioning enabled on your Sharepoint library and particularly, Major and Minor versions?  The reason I ask this is because we have a library where Major and Minor versions are enabled, and only certain people can see the minor version.  This sometimes leads to situations where different people can see different versions of the same document, leading to confusion.  Am wondering if this might be your issue

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your suggestion but no we do not use versioning here, we just overwrite the current file.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, you can use the program in your start menu "Microsoft Office Upload Center" to set cached files to be removed as soon as you close them on the profile used to run these reports.

It will slow you down slightly opening other documents but sounds like the extra time might be worth the extra accuracy.

The link below should help to understand SharePoint's cache process.

[Office Document Cache settings](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Office-Document-Cache-settings-4b497318-ae4f-4a99-be42-b242b2e8b692)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll be trying this for today.  I've had a read over the link you posted and not sure if this will ensure the latest numbers from the reports on SharePoint.  It says "The Office Document Cache is used by the Microsoft Office Upload Center to give you a way to see the state of files you're uploading to a server".  However I am not the one who uploads the files to SharePoint so I'm just making sure this solution will work for me?

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with whoever is trying to use that data connection because the setting should be associated with their own profile and the connection is running from their machine. How did this help?

Comment: I am logged in to Excel which is associated with SharePoint so that's where the credentials are coming from.  Also I'm not sure this is working as I am not the one uploading the documents to SharePoint just trying to grab the figures from them.